# Converting Hex to RGB value in Python

Tags: python, colors, rgb

Working off Jeremy's response here: [Converting hex color to RGB and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-color-to-rgb-and-vice-versa) I was able to get a python program to convert preset colour hex codes (example #B4FBB8), however from an end-user perspective we can't ask people to edit code & run from there. How can one prompt the user to enter a hex value and then have it spit out a RGB value from there?

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
def hex_to_rgb(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(value)
    return tuple(int(value[i:i + lv // 3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv // 3))


def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

hex_to_rgb("#ffffff")              # ==> (255, 255, 255)
hex_to_rgb("#ffffffffffff")        # ==> (65535, 65535, 65535)
rgb_to_hex((255, 255, 255))        # ==> '#ffffff'
rgb_to_hex((65535, 65535, 65535))  # ==> '#ffffffffffff'

print('Please enter your colour hex')

hex == input("")

print('Calculating...')
print(hex_to_rgb(hex()))
```

Using the line `print(hex_to_rgb('#B4FBB8'))` I'm able to get it to spit out the correct RGB value which is (180, 251, 184)

It's probably super simple - I'm still pretty rough with Python.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661725/format-ints-into-string-of-hex

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I believe that this does what you are looking for:

```
h = input('Enter hex: ').lstrip('#')
print('RGB =', tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)))
```

(The above was written for Python 3)

Sample run:

```
Enter hex: #B4FBB8
RGB = (180, 251, 184)
```

#### Writing to a file

To write to a file with handle `fhandle` while preserving the formatting:

```
fhandle.write('RGB = {}'.format( tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)) ))
```

Comment: Beautiful. Cuts 23 lines down to two, only suggestion is fixing to `for i in (0, 2, 4)))`

Comment: Question, John1024, I'm writing the result (example #FFFFFF being (255, 255, 255)) to a file using f.write, it requests it be a string rather than a tuple. Is there any way I can convert it to a string preserving the commas and spaces? Cheers :)

Comment: @JulianWhite No problem.  I updated the answer using string formatting suitable for `f.write`.

Comment: Getting error "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: @Typewar Are you using python3?  (This code would have to be modified if you needed to use it with the soon-to-be-obsolete python2.)  What _exactly_ did you enter in response to the prompt?  What is the full and complete error message that you see?

Comment: Although implied it doesn't, this works in Python 2.7.12 as well. Just remember to `.lstrip('#')` the tkinter color coded being passed to your function.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I get your point but to obtain the same screen output from py2, one should either change the print command to `print 'RGB =', tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))` or else precede the print command with `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @John1024 Gotcha. When I started out with `2.7.12` I was using `print` from the future I forgot all about that problem for others.

Comment: For convenience, the reverse of this, converting a color triple `c` back to a hex string, is `'#' + ''.join(hex(x)[2:].zfill(2) for x in c)`.

Answer (score 55):

You can use `ImageColor` from Pillow.

```
>>> from PIL import ImageColor
>>> ImageColor.getcolor("#23a9dd", "RGB")
(35, 169, 221)
```

Comment: Hey @SuperNova how to get the name of color instead of pixel values?

Comment: hwy @Mvk1312. Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694165/convert-rgb-color-to-english-color-name-like-green-with-python

Answer (score 46):

Just another option: [matplotlib.colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colors_api.html) module.

Quite simple:

```
>>> import matplotlib.colors
>>> matplotlib.colors.to_rgb('#B4FBB8')
(0.7058823529411765, 0.984313725490196, 0.7215686274509804)
```

Note that the input of `to_rgb` need not to be hexadecimal color format, it admits several color formats.

You can also use the deprecated `hex2color`

```
>>> matplotlib.colors.hex2color('#B4FBB8')
(0.7058823529411765, 0.984313725490196, 0.7215686274509804)
```

The bonus is that we have the inverse function, `to_hex` and few extra functions such as, `rgb_to_hsv`.

Answer (score 19):

A lazy option:
[webcolors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3) package has a `hex_to_rgb` function.

Comment: By the way, currently webcolors does not have a `hex_to_rgb` where the tuples are specified in decimal value in range 0 and 1 (say hex_to_rgb_decimal). But, you can use this code that imports numpy and webcolors: `tuple(numpy.array(webcolors.hex_to_rgb('#9C0006'))/255.0)`

Comment: This was apparently the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

PIL also has this function, in ImageColor.

```
from PIL import ImageColor

ImageColor.getrgb("#9b9b9b")
```

And if you want the numbers from 0 to 1

```
[i/256 for i in ImageColor.getrgb("#9b9b9b")]
```

Comment: In case you need values from 0…1:
rgb = [i/256 for i in (ImageColor.getrgb("#9b9b9b"))]

Comment: I believe the last comment to be wrong. 255/256=0.99609. The values returned from `ImageColor.getrbb` are [0 ... 255], hard bounded by 255 upper limit. By dividing 256 you will never reach 1.0. Unless I am very wrong here, I suggest you change this to i/255.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
```

Usage:

```
>>> rgb_to_hex((255, 255, 195))
'ffffc3'
```

---

And for the reverse:

```
def hex_to_rgb(hexa):
    return tuple(int(hexa[i:i+2], 16)  for i in (0, 2, 4))
```

Usage:

```
>>> hex_to_rgb('ffffc3')
(255, 255, 195)
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for.. might want to handle hex strings with leading #, for example the way John1024 did it... something like hexa = hexa.lstrip('#')

Answer (score 6):

This function will return the *RGB* values in float from a *Hex* code.

```py
def hextofloats(h):
    '''Takes a hex rgb string (e.g. #ffffff) and returns an RGB tuple (float, float, float).'''
    return tuple(int(h[i:i + 2], 16) / 255. for i in (1, 3, 5)) # skip '#'
```

---

This function will return *Hex* code from *RGB* value.

```py
def floatstohex(rgb):
    '''Takes an RGB tuple or list and returns a hex RGB string.'''
    return f'#{int(rgb[0]*255):02x}{int(rgb[1]*255):02x}{int(rgb[2]*255):02x}'
```

Comment: `floatstohex([255,255,255])` produces '#fe01fe01fe01', should it not be "#FFFFFF"

Answer (score 5):

As *HEX* codes can be like *`"#FFF"`, `"#000"`, `"#0F0"` or even `"#ABC"` that only use three digits.* These are just the shorthand version of writing a code, which are the three pairs of identical digits `"#FFFFFF"`, `"#000000"`, `"#00FF00"` or `"#AABBCC"`.

---

*This function is made in such a way that it can work with both shorthands as well as the full length of HEX codes. Returns RGB values if the argument **`hsl = False`** else return HSL values.*

```py
import re

def hex_to_rgb(hx, hsl=False):
    """Converts a HEX code into RGB or HSL.
    Args:
        hx (str): Takes both short as well as long HEX codes.
        hsl (bool): Converts the given HEX code into HSL value if True.
    Return:
        Tuple of length 3 consisting of either int or float values.
    Raise:
        ValueError: If given value is not a valid HEX code."""
    if re.compile(r'#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3})?$').match(hx):
        div = 255.0 if hsl else 0
        if len(hx) <= 4:
            return tuple(int(hx[i]*2, 16) / div if div else
                         int(hx[i]*2, 16) for i in (1, 2, 3))
        return tuple(int(hx[i:i+2], 16) / div if div else
                     int(hx[i:i+2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))
    raise ValueError(f'"{hx}" is not a valid HEX code.')
```

---

*Here are some IDLE outputs.*

```py
>>> hex_to_rgb('#FFB6C1')
(255, 182, 193)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#ABC')
(170, 187, 204)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#FFB6C1', hsl=True)
(1.0, 0.7137254901960784, 0.7568627450980392)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#ABC', hsl=True)
(0.6666666666666666, 0.7333333333333333, 0.8)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#00FFFF')
(0, 255, 255)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#0FF')
(0, 255, 255)

>>> hex_to_rgb('#0FFG')  # When invalid hex is given.
ValueError: "#0FFG" is not a valid HEX code.
```

Answer (score 5):

The following function will convert hex string to rgb values:

```
def hex_to_rgb(hex_string):
    r_hex = hex_string[1:3]
    g_hex = hex_string[3:5]
    b_hex = hex_string[5:7]
    return int(r_hex, 16), int(g_hex, 16), int(b_hex, 16)
```

This will convert the hexadecimal_string to decimal number

```
int(hex_string, 16)
```

For example:

```
int('ff', 16) # Gives 255 in integer data type
```

Comment: I found this solution is fastest one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two small errors here!

```
hex == input("")
```

Should be:

```
user_hex = input("")
```

You want to assign the output of `input()` to `hex`, not check for comparison. Also, as mentioned in comments (@koukouviou) don't override `hex`, instead call it something like `user_hex`.

Also:

```
print(hex_to_rgb(hex()))
```

Should be:

```
print(hex_to_rgb(user_hex))
```

You want to use the value of hex, not the type's callable method (`__call__`).

Comment: It is better to avoid overriding `hex`. Maybe something like `hex_in` or similar is better

Comment: Good point, @koukouviou - Python reports it as built-in name.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers I've seen involve manipulation of a hex string. In my view, I'd prefer to work with encoded integers and RGB triples themselves, not just strings. This has the benefit of not requiring that a color be represented in hexadecimal-- it could be in octal, binary, decimal, what have you.

Converting an RGB triple to an integer is easy.

```py
rgb = (0xc4, 0xfb, 0xa1) # (196, 251, 161)

def rgb2int(r,g,b):
    return (256**2)*r + 256*g + b

c = rgb2int(*rgb) # 12909473
print(hex(c))     # '0xc4fba1'
```

We need a little more math for the opposite direction. I've lifted the following from my answer to a similar [Math exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3343322/16221).

```py
c = 0xc4fba1

def int2rgb(n):
    b = n % 256
    g = int( ((n-b)/256) % 256 )      # always an integer
    r = int( ((n-b)/256**2) - g/256 ) # ditto
    return (r,g,b)

print(tuple(map(hex, int2rgb(c)))) # ('0xc4', '0xfb', '0xa1')
```

With this approach, you can convert to and from strings with ease.

Comment: Well the question was about hex.

Comment: It does not answer the question, but it gives insight into how it's done conceptually, so +1. (teach a man how to fish and so on... )

Answer (score 0):

This supports also RGBA converting and short form (`#fff`). It's pretty ugly, but it does the trick.

```py
def parse_hex(h):
    if h[0]=="#":
        h=h[1:]
    try:
        col=int(h,16)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid HEX string") from None

    l=len(h)
    if l== 6: #long form , no alpha
            return (col&0xff0000)>>16,(col&0xff00)>>8,(col&0xff),1
    elif l== 8: #long form, alpha
            scol = col >> 8
            return (scol&0xff0000)>>16,(scol&0xff00)>>8,(scol&0xff),(col&0xff)/255
    elif l == 3: #short form, no alpha
            return 17*((col&0xf00)>>8),17*((col&0xf0)>>4),17*(col&0xf),1
    elif l == 4: #short form, alpha
            print(hex(col))
            return 17*((col&0xf000)>>12),17*((col&0xf00)>>8),17*((col&0xf0)>>4),17*(col&0xf)/255
    else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid HEX string")
```

Answer (score 0):

#Converting Hex to RGB value in Python

```
def hex_to_rgb(h, opacity=.8):
r = g = b = 0
if len(h) == 4:
    r = int(("0x" + h[1] + h[1]), base=16)
    g = int(("0x" + h[2] + h[2]), base=16)
    b = int(("0x" + h[3] + h[3]), base=16)
elif len(h) == 7:
    r = int(("0x" + h[1] + h[2]), base=16)
    g = int(("0x" + h[3] + h[4]), base=16)
    b = int(("0x" + h[5] + h[6]), base=16)
if opacity:
    return f"rgb({r}, {g}, {b}, {opacity})"
return f"rgb({r}, {g}, {b})"
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes the accepted answer, but also handles short form hex codes e.g. *#fff, #000* that can be encountered in the wild.

```
h = input('Enter hex: ').lstrip('#')

if len(h == 3):
  h = ''.join([d + d for d in h])

print('RGB =', tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4)))
```