# *** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error, typeerror

l would like to convert my array of colors to RGB pixel values .

colors

```
array(['#32CD32', '#CD5C5C', '#00BFFF', '#1E90FF', '#00008B', '#ADFF2F',
       '#B0E0E6', '#7CFC00', '#00008B', '#1E90FF', '#F08080', '#F08080',
       '#FA8072', '#0000FF', '#7CFC00', '#B0E0E6'],
      dtype='<U7')
```

What l have tried ?

```
pixel_color = ['#%02x%02x%02x' % (c[0], c[1], c[2]) for c in colors]
```

l got the following error :

***** TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not str**

Then l did the following :

```
pixel_color = ["#%02x%02x%02x" %(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2])) for c in colors]
```

Then l get the following error :

***** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Hex to RGB value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643352/converting-hex-to-rgb-value-in-python)

Comment: Hi @chrisz, thank you for your comment l tried that pixel_color = ["%02x%02x%02x" %(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2])) for c in colors] however l get the same error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'

Comment: Yea because you aren't stripping the `#` from your input

Comment: colors= [c.strip('#') for c in colors] which returns ['32CD32', 'CD5C5C', '00BFFF', '1E90FF', '00008B', 'ADFF2F', 'B0E0E6', '7CFC00', '00008B', '1E90FF', 'F08080', 'F08080', 'FA8072', '0000FF', '7CFC00', 'B0E0E6'] then pixel_color = ["%02x%02x%02x" %(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2])) for c in colors] *** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting that code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't stripping the `#` from your input before you try the conversion.  Also, why don't you just use `bytes.fromhex()`:

```
x = ['#32CD32', '#CD5C5C', '#00BFFF', '#1E90FF', '#00008B', '#ADFF2F',
'#B0E0E6', '#7CFC00', '#00008B', '#1E90FF', '#F08080', '#F08080',
'#FA8072', '#0000FF', '#7CFC00', '#B0E0E6']

for i in x:
  red, green, blue = bytes.fromhex(i[1:])
  print(red, green, blue)
```

Output:

```
50 205 50
205 92 92
0 191 255
30 144 255
0 0 139
173 255 47
176 224 230
124 252 0
0 0 139
30 144 255
240 128 128
240 128 128
250 128 114
0 0 255
124 252 0
176 224 230
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what l'm looking for. Thank you @chrisz

Comment: WARNING: `#` prefix say that what follow is a colour code, not a hex number. You should expand it, if the colour string is just 3 (additinal) characters (short code, very common). This should be done before to convert the number.