# Draw a grid of colors using their hex values

Tags: python, colors, hex, seaborn

I have a list of hex values representing different colors.

How can I represent those hex values in a grid of colors. That is, visualizing the color of each hex value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `seaborn` the most straightforward way would probably be using 'sns.palplot()', for example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

def hex_to_rgb(hex_value):
  h = hex_value.lstrip('#')
  return tuple(int(h[i:i + 2], 16) / 255.0 for i in (0, 2, 4))

hex_colors = [
  '#f0787e', '#f5a841', '#5ac5bc', '#ee65a3', '#f5e34b', '#640587', '#c2c36d',
  '#2e003a', '#878587', '#d3abea', '#f2a227', '#f0db08', '#148503', '#0a6940',
  '#043834', '#726edb', '#db6e6e', '#db6ecb', '#6edb91'
]

rgb_colors = list(map(hex_to_rgb, hex_colors))

sns.palplot(rgb_colors)
```

(credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643643/10990718) for the `hex_to_rgb()` function).

This will result in a single row of colored squares.
To split it into multiple rows, in case there are many entries, one could simply call `sns.palplot()` multiple times, but that would result in a odd layout since the space between the rows would be larger that the space between columns, for example:

```py
row_size = 5
rows = [rgb_colors[i:i + row_size] for i in range(0, len(rgb_colors), row_size)]

for row in rows:
  sns.palplot(row)
```

The other option could be mimicking what `sns.palplot()` does (see [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/0b5653f7e09819e6b8b8f08e5a366a891af9bc8a/seaborn/miscplot.py#L10)) and create *sub plots*:

```py
# Make sure the last row has the same number of elements as the other ones by
# filling it with a default color (white).
rows[-1].extend([(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)] * (row_size - len(rows[-1])))

num_rows = len(rgb_colors) // row_size + 1

f, plots = plt.subplots(num_rows, 1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
for i in range(num_rows):
  plot = plots[i]
  plot.imshow(np.arange(row_size).reshape(1, row_size),
              cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(rows[i]),
              interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
  plot.set_xticks(np.arange(row_size) - .5)
  plot.set_yticks([-.5, .5])
  plot.set_xticklabels([])
  plot.set_yticklabels([])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `n` x `m` colors you can convert to rgba and reshape to `(m, n, 4)`. Eg. for 6x5=30 hex values in a list:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba_array

list_of_hex = [f"#{''.join(np.random.choice(list('0123456789abcdef'), size=6))}" \
               for _ in range(30)]


plt.imshow(to_rgba_array(list_of_hex).reshape(6,5,4))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter, here is a small method that uses Pandas and `df.style.apply`:

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

def display_hex_colors(hex_colors: List[str]):
    """Visualize a list of hex colors using pandas"""
    df = pd.DataFrame(hex_colors).T
    df.columns = hex_colors
    df.iloc[0,0:len(hex_colors)] = ""
    display(df.style.apply(lambda x: apply_formatting(x, hex_colors)))

display_hex_colors(
    ['#3f007d','#52238d','#65489f','#796eb2','#918dc2',
    '#abaad1','#c6c7e1','#dfdeed','#f0eff6','#FFFFFF',
    '#FCF0D8','#fdd49e','#fdbb84','#fc8d59','#ef6548',
    '#d7301f','#b30000','#7f0000','#440402])
```

Looks like:
[image]