# Shape Color in RGB

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to read color of a shape in RGB however, it is coming in hex format...

for shape in slide_3.shapes:
    if shape.name[:9] == 'Rectangle':
        print(shape.fill.fore_color.rgb, shape.line.color.rgb)

72F91E 000000
72F91E 000000
72F91E 000000
72F91E 000000

Comment: Seems to be one similar question: [See That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643352/converting-hex-to-rgb-value-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `shape.fill.fore_color.rgb` is an `RGBColor` object.

`RGBColor` is a subtype of `tuple` and in particular a 3-tuple of `int`. What you're getting with `print()` is the `str` representation which is a triple of two-hex-digit R, G, and B values, commonly used for specifying colors in for instance HTML/CSS.

You can extract the red value with:

```
rgb = shape.fill.fore_color.rgb
red_value = rgb[0]
```

Maybe easier is to unpack the tuple like this:

```
red, green, blue = shape.fill.fore_color.rgb
print("red == %d, green == %d, blue = %d" % (red, green, blue))
```

or more simply:

```
print("red == %d, green == %d, blue = %d" % shape.fill.fore_color.rgb)
```

Comment: Hi Scanny,

Thank you for the detailed explanation. This really helped.

Comment: @KathiravanSaimoorthy Welcome to StackOverflow! You should accept this question (by clicking the checkmark) if it answered your question. This lets others who find it later on search know it is a correct answer. Also, you should vote it up with the up-arrow if you found it helpful. This is how the StackOverflow economy works and why you so often find useful answers here :)