# How to enclose a tuple in quotation marks to use it as string argument in a function?

Tags: python

**Challenge**

How do I get from `(255, 255, 255, 0)` to  `'(255, 255, 255, 0)'` when the former is a tuple?

**Details:**

I'm converting hex colors to rgba colors using an approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643352/converting-hex-to-rgb-value-in-python). I'm doing this to use the color as arguments *with* an opacity element like so:

```
color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
```

As you might already have guessed, the argument has to be of a `string` type.
And I've come so far as having the integers in a tuple like so

```
(255, 255, 255, 0)
```

Now I need to enclose the whole tuple in a string like `'(255, 255, 255, 0)'` to get to my last step:

```
'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
```

I'm afraid I'm missing some obvious and *very* fundamental element of Python here, but any suggestions would be great!

Comment: `'rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(*your_tuple)` should do it, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about casting it in `str`?

```
>>> color = (255, 255, 255, 0)
>>> str(color)
'(255, 255, 255, 0)'
>>> str_color = 'rgba' + str(color)
>>> str_color
'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
```

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid there's no simple conversion function for that, however, this should work:

```py
t = (255, 255, 255, 0)
f'rgba({t[0]}, {t[1]}, {t[2]}, {t[3]})'
```

Even shorter:

```py
t = (255, 255, 255, 0)
f'rgba{str(t)}'
```

Depending on the context, I would probably prefer the first option for two reasons:

1. second option, while shorter, depends on the `str` implementation for tuples. It is unlikely to change, but unlikely does not mean impossible
2. **(the most important)** it just accidentally occurred that `str` view for tuples fits the expected string pattern. Once string pattern changes it may be a nightmare bug to trace and fix.

The first option explicitly separates representation from data, and also allows us to use any iterable, not only tuples. And using a class instead of the tuple, in this case, may be a very robust idea.

Comment: I've submitted an answer on this thread, but I must admit that your last solution is beautifully elegant.

Comment: @JST99 Thank you! Honestly, I would usually prefer the first option, as it would not depend on str implementation staying the same

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use string formatting and tuple unpacking for this:

```
your_tuple = (255, 255, 255, 0)
'rgba({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(*your_tuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply `str((255, 255, 255, 0))`

```py
>>> a = (255, 255, 255, 0)
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> b = str(a)
>>> print(b, type(b))
(255, 255, 255, 0) <class 'str'>
```