# Is there a way to convert HEX or RGB format to text?

Tags: python

My question is if there is any way from Python to convert an RGB or HEX color value to the corresponding text of the color.

Example: * # FFFFFF -> WHITE * or * RGB (255,255,255) -> WHITE *

Comment: What would you expect to get from e.g. `#ABCDEF` ?

Comment: Have you got a full list of the text representations?  There's a defined list of "web colours" but that's not a standard thing, just a way of assigning an arbitrary word with a hex code

Comment: You can refer from here [hex-to-rgb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643352/converting-hex-to-rgb-value-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a lookup table for all the colors you need:

```python
hexToText = {'#FFFFFF':'WHITE', '#FF0000':'RED', '#00FF00':'GREEN', '#0000FF':'BLUE'}

testHex = '#FF0000'
testHexColor = hexToText[testHex] # now has 'RED'

rgbToText = {(255,255,255):'WHITE', (255,0,0):'RED', (0,255,0):'GREEN', (0,0,255):'BLUE'}

testRgb = (0,255,0)
testRgbColor = rgbToText[testRgb] # now has 'GREEN'
```