# function that takes 2 colors as arguments and returns the average color

Tags: python, function, colors, rgb

I'm new to coding and I am trying to complete this assignment, but I can't get it to work:

```
def colorMean(colorA, colorB):
    
    rgb1 = int(colorA, 16)
    rgb2 = int(colorB, 16)
    
    aveColor = 0
    for i in range (3):
        
        comp1 = int(color1 >> (8 * i)) & 0xff
        comp2 = int(color2 >> (8 * i)) & 0xff
        
        value = int((comp1 + comp2) / 2) << 8 * i
        
        avgColor = int((comp1 + comp2) / 2) << 8 * i
        
    return hex(aveColo)


colorMean("0000ff", "ff0000")
```

Comment: You're doing the right thing by breaking each color into independent R,G,B channels with shifting and masking. Where you fail is mixing those averages back together.  And I think you may be missing some parentheses, check your operator precedences.

Comment: You have spelled aveColor three different ways: aveColor avgColor aveColo  ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. If there are restrictions and sample outputs to the assignment, you should post those too.

NOTE: I got the first two function `hex_to_rgb` and `rgb_to_hex` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643352/converting-hex-to-rgb-value-in-python)

```
def hex_to_rgb(value):
   value = value.lstrip('#')
   lv = len(value)
   return tuple(int(value[i:i + lv // 3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv // 3))


def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
   return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb


def mean_color(color1, color2):
   rgb1 = hex_to_rgb(color1)
   rgb2 = hex_to_rgb(color2)

   avg = lambda x, y: round((x+y) / 2)

   new_rgb = ()

   for i in range(len(rgb1)):
      new_rgb += (avg(rgb1[i], rgb2[i]),)
       
   return rgb_to_hex(new_rgb)
```

```
avg_color = mean_color('ff0000', '0000ff')
print(avg_color) # 800080
```

Comment: The parameters will be two 6-digit hexadecimal strings. This does not need to be validated.
* The return value should be a 6-digit hexadecimal string.
* The hexadecimal strings represent colors in RGB, much like in CSS.
* The average color is to be determined by taking the arithmetic mean for each component: red, green and blue.