# string representation of hexadecimal values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie in python.
Can some one advice how can I convert a hex number to its string representation.I would like to implement something like below.What should be the best method for 'convert()'?

```
val_hex = 0xBEEF
val_str = convet(val_hex) # val_str = 'BEEF'
```

Comment: `hex(0xBEEF)` or `"{:x}".format(0xBEEF)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format ints into string of hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661725/format-ints-into-string-of-hex)

Comment: val = "{:x}".format(0xBEEF)

Comment: yes, doesn't that work?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre easier to use `format(0xBEEF, 'x')`...

Comment: Both "{:x}".format(0xBEEF) and format(0xBEEF, 'x') worked as I expected.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Could using builtin function [hex](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=hex#hex), which convert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”

```
hex(val_hex)  # ==> 0xbeef
```

Or using [format % values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), `X` means signed hexadecimal (uppercase)

```
'%X' % val_hex  # ==> BEEF
```