# base64 to hex string

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, base64

I am trying to make a hex string out of a base64 string.
The original string is: `M0SvYeRHPWDYVIG/giptBFqBMQdWObq8br1RDqWfO1rvky6RW0HiGCMQC1mhybYzFeSUkC5iw464P5nCYUc==` 
It should become:

```
3344af61e4473d60d85481bf822a6d04 5a8131075639babc6ebd510ea59f3b5a ef932e915b41e21823100b59a1c9b633 15e494902e62c38eb83f99c26147
```

My code is:

```
str1 = "M0SvYeRHPWDYVIG/giptBFqBMQdWObq8br1RDqWfO1rvky6RW0HiGCMQC1mhybYzFeSUkC5iw464P5nCYUc=="
d = base64.b64decode(str1)
d1 = d.decode('utf-8')
print(d1)
```

However, I get the message in decode utf-8:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 2: invalid start byte
```

The output of d1 is:

```
b'3D\xafa\xe4G=`\xd8T\x81\xbf\x82*m\x04Z\x811\x07V9\xba\xbcn\xbdQ\x0e\xa5\x9f;Z\xef\x93.\x91[A\xe2\x18#\x10\x0bY\xa1\xc9\xb63\x15\xe4\x94\x90.b\xc3\x8e\xb8?\x99\xc2aG'
```

Where is my mistake?
I would also like to see the backwards version from the hex string to base64. 
I use python **3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `base64.b64decode(str1)` is:

- a *`bytes` object* already in Python 3.
- a *`str` object* in Python 2 (and `str` and `bytes` are synonyms here).

The following *commented* script covers both Python versions:

```
import base64
str1 = "M0SvYeRHPWDYVIG/giptBFqBMQdWObq8br1RDqWfO1rvky6RW0HiGCMQC1mhybYzFeSUkC5iw464P5nCYUc=="
d = base64.b64decode(str1)
print(type(d))
print(type(d) is bytes)

# python 2
if type(d) is str:
    d = bytearray(d)

# The old format style was the %-syntax:
d1=''.join(['%02x'%i for i in d])
print(d1)

# The more modern approach is the .format method:
d1=''.join(['{:02x}'.format(i) for i in d])
print(d1)
```

**Result**:

```
py -3 .\SO3\62087693.py
```

> ```
> <class 'bytes'>
> True
> 3344af61e4473d60d85481bf822a6d045a8131075639babc6ebd510ea59f3b5aef932e915b41e21823100b59a1c9b63315e494902e62c38eb83f99c26147
> 3344af61e4473d60d85481bf822a6d045a8131075639babc6ebd510ea59f3b5aef932e915b41e21823100b59a1c9b63315e494902e62c38eb83f99c26147
> ```

```
py -2 .\SO3\62087693.py
```

> ```
> <type 'str'>
> True
> 3344af61e4473d60d85481bf822a6d045a8131075639babc6ebd510ea59f3b5aef932e915b41e21823100b59a1c9b63315e494902e62c38eb83f99c26147
> 3344af61e4473d60d85481bf822a6d045a8131075639babc6ebd510ea59f3b5aef932e915b41e21823100b59a1c9b63315e494902e62c38eb83f99c26147
> ```

Note: [more recently, from Python 3.6 upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57197866/3439404) there is a [*f-string* syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (but I had frozen at version 3.5.1 so this isn't proved by an example):

```
''.join([f'{i:02x}' for i in d])
```