# Extract RGB or 6 digit code from Seaborn palette

Tags: python, rgb, seaborn

Seaborn has an option to create nice color palettes. I wish to use these palettes to generate colors that work well together in a map where countries are shaded according to some property. The following code produces 8 shades of purple from light to dark. Note also the ability to specify the number of colors is required so I cannot just use a fixed palette of defined colors.

```
import seaborn as sns
num_shades = 8
sns.palplot(sns.cubehelix_palette(num_shades))
```

If I run the same but in a list like so:

```
color_list = sns.cubehelix_palette(num_shades)
```

you get:

```
[[0.9312692223325372, 0.8201921796082118, 0.7971480974663592], ...
```

These are clearly not RGB values which is what I need.

1) What format are these colors in?
2) How can I convert to RGB or 6 digit codes?

I have tried searching for quite some time and found no answers. I have looked here and at other seaborn documentation:

https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.set_color_codes.html

I can convert to 6 digit codes from RGB using:

[Converting a RGB color tuple to a six digit code, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python)

but am stuck as to how to do it direct or via getting the RGB values. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The values you are getting are percentages of 255, the max RGB value.
Just multiply each triplet of values by 255 (and round off, if you like) to get the RGB values.

```
for color in color_list:
    for value in color:
        value *= 255
```

Then store those in a new list to have your list of RGB values.

Answer (score 94):

If by "6 digit code" you mean a hex code, you can also do:

```
pal = sns.color_palette(...)
pal.as_hex()
```

Comment: Works! It returns a list of strings with the # added. See: `import seaborn; pal_hls = seaborn.hls_palette(12, l=.3, s=.8).as_hex(); print(pal_hls);`

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer works, but it manually reinvents the wheel instead of using an existing built-in function

Answer (score 3):

Just adding a point to @mwaskom answer as I am not allowed to comment yet.

```
pal = sns.color_palette(...)
pal.as_hex()
```

This in my case was giving colors as shown in the image1 (using python 3.9),
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXkm6.png)

If you want color hex codes, you can slice it like this:

```
pal = sns.color_palette(...)
pal.as_hex()[:]
```

For a particular color, say the first color, use this:

```
pal = sns.color_palette(...)
pal.as_hex()[0]
```