# How to get all color codes from LinearSegmentedColormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to make a colormap and using the below code:

```
import seaborn as sns

cmap = sns.color_palette("dark:#034694", as_cmap=True)
```

Now I want the list of all the color-codes from this `cmap`, its type is `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`. What should I do to get all the color-codes from the variable `cmap`.

Comment: Maybe this link might help: https://python-graph-gallery.com/100-calling-a-color-with-seaborn/

Comment: This gives all the colors seaborn has like black, red, blue etc, instead I want all the color codes for the `cmap` variable that I created using the above script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract RGB or 6 digit code from Seaborn palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249454/extract-rgb-or-6-digit-code-from-seaborn-palette)

Comment: No, it says `'LinearSegmentedColormap' object is not iterable` when I tried the first answer.

Comment: `LinearSegmentedColormap` is generative, it doesn't contain a defined set of color codes that you could get "all" of. It might help if you give some more context for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mwaskom I don't understand this comment. `cmap.N` provides us with the number of colors of the `LinearSegmentedColormap` (256 in this case), so why does it not contain a defined set of colors? Strangely enough, `sns.color_palette("dark:#034694").as_hex()` contains only 6 entries. Why does the matplotlib `LinearSegmentedColormap` consists then of 256 entries?

Comment: @Mr.T Internally there is a lookup table with a defined resolution, but it's a private attribute. If you want a defined number of discrete hex colors from `seaborn.color_palette`, generally you would not add `as_cmap=True`. That's why I'm trying to understand the context of the question better.

Comment: I want to extract the color-codes from a color-pallete. The below solution answers the question. Just I have to use `mpl.colors.rgb2hex()` method on the list values to get the color codes.

Comment: But why add `as_cmap`? You get the color codes directly if you don't do that.

Comment: If I just do this `sns.color_palette("dark:#034694")`, it is giving me a colorbar, instead I want all the color-codes used in building that colorbar

Comment: You mean like the already mentioned: `sns.color_palette("dark:#034694").as_hex()`?

Comment: Ah! it seems that there are multiple ways to do it. This code is again returning R,G,B and A values then again we have to use `mpl.colors.rgb2hex() ` to get the hexcodes.

Comment: `print(sns.color_palette("dark:#034694").as_hex())` returns `['#23262d', '#1d2c41', '#163356', '#10396b', '#09407f', '#034694']`, not sure why you think these are RGBA values.

Comment: Oh! I was trying without the print statement in the jupyter notebook and it was giving me a colorbar. Also your code only gives 6 hex-codes. But the below answer is giving all the hexcodes that are in the color-palette. So, I think the below solution answers the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### clumsy workaround

The idea is to get more colors than are contained in the colormap and then limit the result to the unique colours.

```
list(set([cmap(a) for a in np.linspace(0,1,1000)]))
```

#### longer answer

looking into the [source](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#LinearSegmentedColormap)
we can see that LinearSegmentedColormap inherits from Colormap, meaning that
the `__call__` method of `Colormap` will be executed when we do something like `cmap(0.5)`.

Looking at this method:

> ```
>     def __call__(self, X, alpha=None, bytes=False):
>         
>         [...]
>         
>         if not self._isinit:
>             self._init()
>
>         [...]
>
>         if bytes:
>             lut = (self._lut * 255).astype(np.uint8)
>         else:
>             lut = self._lut.copy()  # Don't let alpha modify original _lut.
>
>         [...]
>
>         rgba = lut[xa]
>         if not np.iterable(X):
>             # Return a tuple if the input was a scalar
>             rgba = tuple(rgba)
>         return rgba
> ```

```
[omissions mine]
```

we can see that the lookup table `self._lut` is initialised by `self._init()`, stored in `lut` and optionally scaled.

i could not find when exactly `_init()` is defined.

in any case, we can call `_init()` and then access the lookup table:

```
cmap = sns.color_palette("dark:#034694", as_cmap=True)
cmap._init()

rgbas = cmap._lut
```

and then convert to hex as pointed out in your comment

```
hexes = [matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in rgbas]
```