# Convert numpy array of RGB values to hex using format operator %

Tags: python, numpy, colors, format

Following on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python) what would be the best way to use the formatting operator to apply it to a numpy array where the array is of the format given below corresponding to RGB values

> Note RGB values have been scaled 0 to 1 so multiple by 255 to rescale

```
array([[ 0.40929448,  0.47071505,  0.27701891],
       [ 0.59383913,  0.60611158,  0.55329837],
       [ 0.4393785 ,  0.4276561 ,  0.34999225],
       [ 0.4159481 ,  0.4516056 ,  0.3026519 ],
       [ 0.54449997,  0.36963636,  0.4001209 ],
       [ 0.36970012,  0.3145826 ,  0.315974  ]])
```

and you want a [hex triplet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) value for each row

Comment: `&` is not a formatting operator. Do you mean `%`? Also, can you given an example of what you want the output to look like? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Corrected and updated my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `rgb2hex` from matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.colors import rgb2hex

[ rgb2hex(A[i,:]) for i in range(A.shape[0]) ]
# ['#687847', '#979b8d', '#706d59', '#6a734d', '#8b5e66', '#5e5051']
```

If you would rather not like the matplotlib function, you will need to convert your array to `int` before using the referenced SO answer. Note that there are slight differences in the output which I assume to be due to rounding errors.

```
B = np.array(A*255, dtype=int) # convert to int

# Define a function for the mapping
rgb2hex = lambda r,g,b: '#%02x%02x%02x' %(r,g,b)

[ rgb2hex(*B[i,:]) for i in range(B.shape[0]) ]
# ['#687846', '#979a8d', '#706d59', '#6a734d', '#8a5e66', '#5e5050']
```

Comment: Hi @Niklas could you explain whats happening in the code you use `[ rgb2hex(*B[i,:]) for i in range(B.shape[0]) ]`

Comment: Sure. The outer ```[ ]``` brackets denote a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This loops over ```range``` and creates an element for each pass (check ```[ i for i in range(4) ]```). In each pass, one row of ```B```, i.e. ```B[:,i]``` is used as input for the function ```rgb2hex```. Since this function expects three inputs, the ```*``` expands the row which would be one single argument otherwise (see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993732/1922650) SO question).