# How can I convert an array of images to a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, rgb, reshape

I have a numpy array of images in that shape:

```
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

- `50000` is the number of images
- `32, 32` are the height and width
- `3` are the RGB values with a range of `0-1`

I would like to convert it to a 2D shape of:

```
(50000, 1024)
```

Here I would have 50000 images represented in one row,
the RGB value would be converted to let's say an hexadecimal value
I've went through a lot of conversion processes into stack overflow and I've found some.
I know that if my array was a 3D array with an already converted value I could easily use `reshape()`function to convert it to 2D.
Now what I'm searching is the easiest way to convert RGB values and reshape my array

Would this be possible in 1 or two lines or should I use an external function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001349/convert-numpy-array-of-rgb-values-to-hex-using-format-operator

Comment: @taras thanks didn't find this one that helps but doesn't resolve all my problem as I would like to see the best code for the whole process. I'm new to python so I'm afraid by playing with the arrays alone I won't take the best way possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the RGB values in the last dimension to the HEX value using whatever function you like. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python) may help.

Reshape then works on any number of dimensions:

```
import numpy as np

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)

vfunc = np.vectorize(rgb2hex)

a = (np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,5,5,3))*255).astype(int)

c = vfunc(a[:,:,:,0], a[:,:,:,1], a[:,:,:,2])

c.reshape((10,25))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but will it convert my RGB value?

Comment: great could you show me the process of conversion please? for loop, one line for loop???

Comment: Just note that I made a fix. Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190501/discussion-between-jurgen-strydom-and-jsmith).

Answer (score 1):

The following combines the RGB values into a single value

```
x=np.zeros((100,32,32,3))
x[:,:,:,0] = np.trunc(x[:,:,:,0]) + np.trunc(x[:,:,:,1] *256) + np.trunc(x[:,:,:,2] *65535)
y=x[:,:,:,0]
print(y.shape)
```

The resulting shape of y: (100, 32, 32)

Next you can use the reshape function on y.

Comment: I've just tried your solution but I still the same shape with the 3 length array at the end. Thanks in advance

Comment: I added some details. If I run the code I get a shape of 100,32,32

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, you firstly need to reshape the `ndarray` ([`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)):

```
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(500, 32, 32, 3))
a_r = np.reshape(a, (500, 1024, 3))
print(a_r.shape)
# (500, 1024, 3)
```

Now, in order to convert the `RGB` values along the last dimension to hexadecimal representation as you suggest, you could define a function that returns a hexadecimal representation of the three values with a simple string formatting:

```
def rgb_to_hex(x):
    return '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*rgb.reshape(3))
```

In order to apply the conversion along all rows in the last axis, you can use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
a_new = np.apply_along_axis(rgb2hex, axis=-1, arr=a_r).shape
print(a_new.shape)
# (500, 1024)
```