# How can I get the background color of an HTML table's row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have an HTML table that I need to not only get the text in any of the rows.
But I would also like to get each and every row's background-color. By using the inspector I can see the "tr class" definition and I already know (and can also verify) that the name "minor" means yellow background (#fff455).

But when I tried to get the row's attributes, by using selenium, I only get None as a result. I have tried to use both the CSS Selector:

```
row0_fault = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("tr.minor")
```

and the tag name:

```
faultTable_rows = Fault_Table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
```

in order to refer to the whole row. And then I tried

```
get_attribute("background-color")
```

but without any success.

Here is the relevant inspector screen capture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ? How can I get the background-color that stands behind the name "minor" ?

Comment: Use element.value_of_css_property("background-color")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_of_css_property()` to get the color as `rgb( , , )`

```
row0_fault = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("tr.minor")
row0_fault.value_of_css_property('background-color')
```

To convert it to hex you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380739/5168011).