# How to get background-color in hex format from element using Robot Framework

Tags: hex, robotframework, rgb

I try this way and use SeleniumLibrary and I use Python 2.7.16

```
    ${elements}    Get Webelement    (//div[@class="slds-col call-scripticon"])[1]
    ${bg color}    Call Method    ${elements}    value_of_css_property    background-color
```

but I got rgb(36, 6, 66)
I don't know how to get color in #240642 format

HTML

```
<div class="slds-col call-scripticon" data-aura-rendered-by="2:7200;a" xpath="1"></div>
```

Style

```
    element.style {
}
.call-scripticon {
   background-color: #240642;
}
```

Anyone help me please.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a keyword in python that transform colors from RGB to HEX.

Let's say you create a module named testLibrary.py in where you will create the python method that change the format of colors:

```
def transform_RGB_to_HEX(arg1):
    hex_result = "".join([format(val, '02X') for val in arg1])
    return hex_result
```

The only thing you need to do now is import the test library in your robot file and call the keyword as you would do with an already existing one.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | MyLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Example that get color in format RGB and transform it into HEX
|  ${elements}  |  Get Webelement  |  (//div[@class="slds-col call-scripticon"])[1]
|  ${bg color}  |  Call Method     |  ${elements}        |   value_of_css_property    | background-color 
|  ${hex_color} |  transform RGB to HEX |  ${bg color}
```

Comment: I don't know if OP tried this but it is not valid in python 2.X. the '02X' is not supoorted in Python 2, just 3