# Hex Color generator RGB in Python

Tags: python, rgb

Can anyone help me with this exercise in python?

**ASK:**
Create a function that accepts three integers that represent the RGB values and outputs the hex-code representation.

**SAMPLE**
100
200
233

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**
#64c8e9

Comment: Read [this](https://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2017/02/rgb-to-hex-understanding-the-major-web-color-codes/) please :) This will help you

Comment: Kindly do a little research before asking questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a RGB color tuple to a six digit code, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-a-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-six-digit-code-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in  **format operator**

```py
print('#%02x%02x%02x' % (100,200,233))
```

will output `#64c8e9`