# Convert rbga to 32 int in python

Tags: python

I have an rbga color in format of r = 255, g = 0, b = 0, a = 255 and I Need to convert it to a 32 bit int in format of this: `0xRRGGBBAA`.

How  should i Do this in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an RGB color tuple to a hexidecimal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380726/converting-an-rgb-color-tuple-to-a-hexidecimal-string)

Comment: No It doeasn't answer it only converts it to hext but i need to be in `0xRRGGBBAA` format

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I read the format wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
r, g, b, a = 255, 0, 0, 255    # red color
```

Shift the position of `r`, `g`, `b` to the left by `24`, `16` and `8` bits, respectively to have their position in the 32-bit integer.

```
rgba_int = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a
```

or

```
rgba_int = (r << 24) + (g << 16) + (b << 8) + a
```

Print the result:

```
print(rgba_int)
```

Output is `4278190335`

Convert the integer back to hexadecimal format to check:

```
rgba_hex = hex(rgba_int)
print(rgba_hex)
```

Output is `0xff0000ff` (red color)

From `rgba_hex`, shift corresponding bits to the right, we have `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a` back to color format:

```
rgba_hex = int(rgba_hex, 16)
r = rgba_hex >> 24 & 0xFF
g = rgba_hex >> 16 & 0xFF
b = rgba_hex >> 8 & 0xFF
a = rgba_hex >> 0 & 0xFF
print(r)
print(g)
print(b)
print(a)
```

Output is `255, 0, 0, 255` (red color)