# what's the max range for colors in this format: #AABBCC?

Tags: python, colors

How can I convert colors from (N, N, N) format to #AABBCC (and #AAABBBCCC) ?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean basic hex values for colours? Where `AA` = red, `BB`=green and `CC`=blue, ranging from `00` to `FF`? (0-255)

Comment: @Slokun yeah.. my problem is that I don't know how to convert between formats.. from (0,1,0) to #00FF00 to (000, 256, 000). (using Python)

Comment: @Patrick - then you should rephrase your question.  You don't mention conversion or Python.

Comment: @Ryan Emerle I guess it is better to create a new question then

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-to-rgb-and-vice-versa/

Comment: @Patrick - if you want to use it in Python, edit your question, add the 'python' tag and there's already a python answer for you below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#FFFFFF`, so simple

every single char has `0..F` range. That is `0..15`. So two chars is `0..(16*16-1) -> 0-255`

To convert between formats just think about:

`#AABBCC` are three values `AA BB CC`. Every single value represents a channel (red, green, blue) that can span from `0` to `255` or from `0` to `FF` or from `0.0` to `1.0`

if you have for example #123456 you can do

```
12 -> 1*16 + 2 = .. (result in range 0-255)
34 -> 3*16 + 4 = ..
56 -> 5*16 + 6 = ..
```

in general a two digits hex number composed by `XY` can be converted to an decimal value by multiplying `X` by 16 and adding `Y`, taking care of converting digits that are over 9 (A, B, C, D, E, F) to their counterparts (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15). So for example `AC` would be `A*16 + C = 10*16 + 12`.

(To be really precise a n digit hex number is converted by multiplying the i-th digit from right by 16^i and adding all of them together)

Comment: In the second line, I think you mean `0-15` and `0-(16*16-1) -> 0-255`.

Comment: ye, sry, let me fix that.. otherwise it would be misleading :)

Answer (score 1):

From 00 to FF. It is hexacecimal for 0 to 255.

Comment: Sorry.. my problem is that I don't know how to convert between formats.. from (0,1,0) to #00FF00 to (000, 256, 000)  (using Python)

Comment: No worries, but please try to phrase this and future questions better :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 RRGGBB    RRGGBB
#000000 - #FFFFFF
 Black  -  White

RR = 00 - FF or 0 - 255
GG = 00 - FF or 0 - 255
BB = 00 - FF or 0 - 255
```

Comment: OK... my problem is that I don't know how to convert between formats.. from (0,1,0) to #00FF00 to (000, 256, 000) (using Python)

Comment: @Patrick: First convert the value 0..1 to 0..255, then convert it to hexadecimal. The first part is easy, you just multiply the value by 255 (or 0xFF). There are a number of ways to do the conversion to hex. You can use string interpolation (`%` operator), or the builtin `hex()` function, or a lookup table. See the various answers people (including myself) have posted to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Those are hexidecimal representations of 16 bit numbers for the Red Green and Blue channels.  So 0 to 255 for each channel. FF (hex) is equal to 255 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `00`-`FF`.

Here's an overview of HTML colors in hex notation:
http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_colors.asp

You can find out how to convert from hex to decimal here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

And, for Python:
[Converting hex color to RGB and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-to-rgb-and-vice-versa/214657#214657)

Or search for "**convert hex decimal**"

Answer (score 0):

This is hexadecimal (base 16) notation, where each digit goes from 0 to 15 (F).

The range of 0 to FF in hexadecimal is 0 to 255 in decimal.

If you want to convert from one to another, there are plenty of sites that will do that for you - like [this one](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php).

Comment: F is equivalent to 15, not 16.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python? Try this:

```
c = (0., 1., 0.)
rgb = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (c[0] * 255, c[1] * 255, c[2] * 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

The min and max values for colors in the #AABBCC format is #000000...#FFFFFF, or 0...16777215 in decimal. Each individual color component ranges from #00..#FF, which is 0..255 in decimal and requires 8-bits or 1 byte of storage. For #AAABBBCCC the range of components is #000-#FFF or 0..4095 each and they require 12-bits or 1½ bytes of storage.

Not sure what the range of values is for N in (N, N, N), but if it's 0..1 then these two functions will convert from it to either 8-bit component #AABBCC or 12-bit component #AAABBBCCC color values (without rounding). Note that the output of each function is a string with the value shown after each print statement below. `ITOH8` and `ITOH12` are constant lookup tables used by the corresponding function.

```
ITOH8 = [('%02X' % i) for i in range(0x100)]

rgbconv8 = lambda c: ''.join( ['#'] + [ITOH8[int(v*0xFF)] for v in c] )

print rgbconv8((0., 1., 0.)) #00FF00
print rgbconv8((.2, .6, .75)) #3399BF

ITOH12 = [('%03X' % i) for i in range(0x1000)]

rgbconv12 = lambda c: ''.join( ['#'] + [ITOH12[int(v*0xFFF)] for v in c] )

print rgbconv12((0., 1., 0.)) #000FFF000
print rgbconv12((.2, .6, .75)) #333999BFF
```