# IPython Notebook for a Game

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been using IPython Notebook for a while now and enjoy its ability to mix text, code and embedded images. Is it possible to use it for interactive applications that require user-input like games?

Currently, I am using `raw_input` for getting a user input. But this is not very useful for a game like Space Invaders. I did a quick search of the  IPython Notebook Gallery, but couldn't find any relevant examples. Any pointers?

Comment: I think `tkinter` is pretty good for loading images. To do small games you can use pygame.

Comment: Thanks! To be clear I am ideally looking for a game than can be embedded in the IPython Notebook web interface itself. Like a browser game.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get some degree of user interactivity using `matplotlib`'s [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html) and [custom event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614949/interactive-image-plotting-with-matplotlib), such as capturing mouse clicks. Combined with [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [`imshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) would probably be the best place to start.

Good luck!

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently no support for interactive plots in the *inline* backend of matplotlib. That means, interactivity in the Notebook itself is limited, and to get interactive plots you'd have to spawn a plot window using any of the other backends (Qt, GTk, etc) There are plans to fix this in the future though.