# Plotting interactive images with python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, interactive, matplotlib-widget

Basically, I want to plot images using `matplotlib` such that I want to control them actively.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614949/interactive-image-plotting-with-matplotlib) link, but it does not seem to quite answer the question.

I have written a program which applies Canny's algorithm (an image-processing algorithm which is used for edge-detection) to an image and displays it using `matplotlib`.

```
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(canny(original_img, kernel_size), cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edited Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

But, the Canny's Algorithm function (`canny(image, kernel_size)`) takes `kernel_size` as an integer input which can be varied. Now, when I want to change the value of the variable, I have to run the program again to get the resultant output image with different `kernel_size`. But it would be much helpful if I am able to change the `kernel_value` actively through the matplotlib window (like using a slider/arrow keys/integer input).
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you come across https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/textbox.html ?

Comment: Thank you, that was super-useful!