# setting tickslabel in matplotlib disables mouse cursor position

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Whenever I plot something in matplotlib, moving the mouse over the plot shows at the bottom the x and y position of the cursor. This is very convenient when exploring data.

Now, If I set the ticklabels to something else, the x position of the cursor at the bottom of the plot is empty, while the gui keeps track of the y position. Is there a way to keep getting the x position?

This is a simple example of this happening:

```
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x=np.linspace(0,np.pi)
y=np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks([0,np.pi/2,np.pi])
ax.set_xticklabels(['0','pi/2','pi'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Interesting. As a side note, if you use `['0',r'$\pi/2$',r'$\pi$']` you can get the labels rendered as TeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do this.

When you set the labels with a list of strings you set the `xaxis.major_formatter` to be `FixedFormatter` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatterhttp://) which has some peculiar behavior to make it work (it always returns `''`, unless you give it a third argument which given when it labels the x-axis, but not otherwise).   The marking of where the cursor is is generated using the `major_formatter` and when you call a `FixedFormatter` it returns `''`, which is what is displayed.

If you *really* want this, you have to write your own call back, see [Color values in imshow for matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836560/color-values-in-imshow-for-matplotlib) for a starting point.  (or subclass `axes` and re-implement `format_coord` (around line 2903 in axes.py in current matplotlib master branch)