# Shifting x-values of a list plotted in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

After performing an FFT and FFTShift on a list (size 1024), I'm now trying to plot the output. I've encountered a couple of problems with trying to display the data exactly how I'd like to.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HTpiX.png]

Currently the x-axis displays the bin numbers. Following the FFT shift, the frequency 0 Hz is at bin number 512 and each bin is worth an additional 2000/1024 Hz, so bin 0 should be -1000 Hz and bin 1023 should be +1000 Hz; bin 1 should be -998.05 Hz and bin 1022 should be +998.05, etc.

I've tried using xticks to display this:

```
xlocs, xlabs = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks([0,(len(a)*0.25),(len(a))/2,(len(a)*0.75),len(a)],[(-1000),(-500),0,500,1000])
```

But then I'm unable to actually read the x-values at specific points on the graph, instead only displaying the y-value and x=. Is there any way I can fix this?

Additionally, I'd also like to translate the whole graph to the left by 302 bins. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the way in which you plot the graph, i.e. calculate the frequencies from the bins before you plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = np.arange(-512, 512)
x = 2000.*bins/1024
plt.plot(x, fft_data)
```

You can then adjust the displayed frequency range by using `plt.xlim`

Comment: What was your second problem? Translating the graph? What do you mean by that? Do you just want to adjust the value ranges of the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the helper function [`fftfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq) which will give you the properly scaled frequencies.  You can then apply `fftshift` to both the `fft` and `freq` arrays.  If you then plot as

```
plot(freq,fft_vals)
```

you will get the results you want.

The reason that you can not read the `x` values off when you manually set the xticks is that you can put *anything* in as the tick labels (such as strings, non-monotonic sequences etc) so matplotlib does not know how to determine the `x` value at an arbitrary point on the canvas (see [setting tickslabel in matplotlib disables mouse cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605646/setting-tickslabel-in-matplotlib-disables-mouse-cursor-position/12607095#12607095)).