# mapping of a non geographical layout in python

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, leaflet, mapbox

Im trying to create a map of a casino floor where you can hover over a machine and it will display a popup of current performance data. I have been trying to find an example but have had no luck. All mapping examples i can find are geographical only. There is an example of Citybike locations in NYC where i like the way it works, but i cannot apply it to a non geographical map. I dont need any help with code, i just need an example, i know theyre out there, i just cannot seem to find it. any help would be appreciated. Even a link on how to create objects on a png or similar image of a casino floor that i could hover over to link to the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `imshow` to display your floor plan as an image.
You might want to check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836560/color-values-in-imshow-for-matplotlib): the code example given in there already returns the coordinates of the point on which the user clicks.