# How to Convert This RGB format in Python

Tags: python, math, colors

I am reading values from something in Python.  The values come in a strange format.  The documentation says:

> ```
> Color is represented by a single value from 0 to 8355711. The RGB(r,g,b) function calculates
> ((R*127 x 2^16) + (G*127 x 2^8) + B*127), where R, G and B are values between 0.00 and 1.00
> ```

Som, a red color has the value of `16712965` I would love to know how to 'unpack' those values as a tuple or something but am struggling with that math.  If this is not possible, a way to convert that value to an rgb value somehow would be great.  Please help! Thanks

Comment: Did you try dividing?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how I can split the one integer into three...

Comment: All it is doing is converting it to hex (multiplying by powers of 2 is the same as bit shifts). Try googling converting back and forth between hex and rgb, it's covered all over the place including so, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-color-to-rgb-and-vice-versa

Comment: Did you try modulus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have mistake in text

- Red=16712965=0xFF0505h
- is out of range of your claimed limit 8355711=7F7F7Fh

So what exactly is your source and destination color format ???

- the most common is 8bit per R,G,B channel packed into 32 bit value
- yours looks like 8bit per channel (7bit used) packed into ?? bit value

What exactly you want ?

- double R,G,B values in range <0.0,1.0> from int col?
- not a python coder in C++ it looks like this:

  ```
  // 8(7 used) bit per channel
  double R=double(col>>16)/127.0;
  double G=double(col>> 8)/127.0;
  double B=double(col    )/127.0;

  // 8 bit per channel
  double R=double(col>>16)/255.0;
  double G=double(col>> 8)/255.0;
  double B=double(col    )/255.0;
  ```
- `x>>n` means arithmetic bit shift right (padding zeros to MSB bit) of value x by n bits
- it is the same as `x/(2^n)`

If you want different conversions then you must specify it.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error. Not sure how that happened.  You explained it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the 2^8 an 2^16 in the formula, this suggest that you can use something akin to right shift in C. Dividing the input number by 2^8=256 is equivalent to 8 bit right shift. Another point to note here is that your R,G,B output values are real numbers. So you would like to use the `float` function during your calculations.

```
c = 8355711
print 'input colour', c

# conversion to RGB format
B = float( c % 256 )/127.0
c = c / 256
G = float( c % 256)/127.0
c = c / 256
R = float( c % 256)/127.0

print R, G, B

# reverse calculation for verifying the result
colour = int((R*127 * 65536) + (G*127 * 256) + B*127)
print colour
```

Comment: This seems very very close, however, I am not sure my math is correct: For instance, when I try your result with the following:

`c = 8912743
B = float( c % 256 )/127.0
c = c / 256
G = float( c % 256)/127.0
c = c / 256
R = float( c % 256)/127.0

print(R, G, B)

colour = int((R*127 * 65536) + (G*127 * 256) + B*127)
print(colour)`

The same value is not returned (it is however very close).  similarly, the RGB values seem to be between something other than 0 - 1 (between 1 and three perhaps?)

Comment: @Startec with the information you've given `8912743` should be an invalid color, the only way to produce it is with `G=2.0079`.