# Change seaborn boxplot line rainbow color

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I found this beautiful graph online (apparently made with plotly) and wanted to recreate it with seaborn.
[image]

This is my code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = ...

flierprops = dict(marker='o', markersize=3)
sns.boxplot(x="label", y="mean",palette="husl", data=data,saturation=1,flierprops=flierprops)
```

and this the outcome so far:

[image]

I'm quite happy already, but I'd like to adjust the line and the outlier colors to match the `husl` color pallette. How can I do this? (and additional: How would I change the line width?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider two SO solutions:

1. [@tmdavison's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893152/1422451) to edit the Line2D objects for line and point colors
2. [@IanHincks's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601444/1422451) to light/darken matplotlib colors for borders

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_tools = ['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia']

### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(4122018)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.choice(data_tools, 500),
                          'int': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500),
                          'num': np.random.randn(500),
                          'bool': np.random.choice([True, False], 500),
                          'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-04-12'), 500)
                           }, columns = ['group', 'int', 'num', 'char', 'bool', 'date'])
```

**Plot** *(generates two: original and adjusted)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import colorsys
import seaborn as sns

def lighten_color(color, amount=0.5):  
    # --------------------- SOURCE: @IanHincks ---------------------
    try:
        c = mc.cnames[color]
    except:
        c = color
    c = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*mc.to_rgb(c))
    return colorsys.hls_to_rgb(c[0], 1 - amount * (1 - c[1]), c[2])

# --------------------- SOURCE: @tmdavison ---------------------    
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(12,6))                           
sns.set()

flierprops = dict(marker='o', markersize=3)
sns.boxplot(x="group", y="num", palette="husl", data=random_df, saturation=1, 
           flierprops=flierprops, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Original Plot Output")

sns.boxplot(x="group", y="num", palette="husl", data=random_df, saturation=1, 
            flierprops=flierprops, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("\nAdjusted Plot Output")

for i,artist in enumerate(ax2.artists):
    # Set the linecolor on the artist to the facecolor, and set the facecolor to None
    col = lighten_color(artist.get_facecolor(), 1.2)
    artist.set_edgecolor(col)    

    # Each box has 6 associated Line2D objects (to make the whiskers, fliers, etc.)
    # Loop over them here, and use the same colour as above
    for j in range(i*6,i*6+6):
        line = ax2.lines[j]
        line.set_color(col)
        line.set_mfc(col)
        line.set_mec(col)
        line.set_linewidth(0.5)   # ADDITIONAL ADJUSTMENT

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Outputs]

---

For your specific plot, set up an axes for the boxplot, then iterate through its MPL artists:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))      
sns.boxplot(x="label", y="mean",palette="husl", data=data, saturation=1,
            flierprops=flierprops, ax=ax)

for i,artist in enumerate(ax.artists):
    # Set the linecolor on the artist to the facecolor, and set the facecolor to None
    col = lighten_color(artist.get_facecolor(), 1.2)
    artist.set_edgecolor(col)    

    # Each box has 6 associated Line2D objects (to make the whiskers, fliers, etc.)
    # Loop over them here, and use the same colour as above
    for j in range(i*6,i*6+6):
        line = ax.lines[j]
        line.set_color(col)
        line.set_mfc(col)
        line.set_mec(col)
        line.set_linewidth(0.5)
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I searched for!