# Python matplotlib intersection between 2 plots to get the colour of only one of them

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I'm plotting more than 10,000 lines with the same colour on a single matplotlib plot. I use alpha=0.1 for transparency.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plt(x[i], y[i], color='b', alpha=0.1)
```

In the intersections between the lines, the colour becomes darker as the colours of the lines "add up".

How can I make the intersections the same colour of a single line?

(I prefer not to find the intersections as there are so many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a *lighter* color in place of using `alpha` for transparency. You can do that as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601444/9214357): you can define a function to which to pass two parameters:

- the name of the color you want to use, `'blue'` for example
- a value which indicates the lightness of the color;

  - 0 total black
  - 1 natural color (`'blue'` as is)
  - 2 total white

In your case you can use a value of `1.9` in order to keep the color very light.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)


def adjust_lightness(color, amount=0.5):
    import matplotlib.colors as mc
    import colorsys
    try:
        c = mc.cnames[color]
    except:
        c = color
    c = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*mc.to_rgb(c))
    return colorsys.hls_to_rgb(c[0], max(0, min(1, amount * c[1])), c[2])



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(20):
    y = np.random.randn(N)
    ax.plot(x, y, color = adjust_lightness('blue', 1.9), linewidth = 3)

plt.show()
```

[image]