# How do I convert three integers into to colors and display them as a color filled square

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I have three set of numbers which I would like to convert into a color ... Where one value is red , other is blue,and the final is green...And finally obtain a color!I want to display it like the image how do I do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting hex color to RGB and vice-versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-color-to-rgb-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Have a look at the Python [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/colorsys.html#module-colorsys) library. Also please edit your question to show possible input and expected output examples.