# How to assign a single color to a pixel region?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Let's say we have one guy wearing a blue shirt. I built haarcascade classifier which detect the shirt object. Once it detect the blue shirt object, how can I get the **hexadecimal color** value of the blue shirt?

`input: image` -> `output: #0000FF` (output can be multiple colors if it's possible)

I want to get this result using OpenCV with python or C++. Any useful link or paper? (I've googled it more than an hours but can't find what I want)

Thanks.!!

Comment: hexcode for color is just 3 hex encoded byte values concatenated, so read the red-channel, the green-channel and the blue-channel, convert the byte value to hex-string and combine them all in a single string. In which of those steps do you have problems to solve it yourself? Here are some examples: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.htm

Comment: Yes but how can it decide it? do we take an average of the certain region? How do we do that?

Comment: so your question instead is "How to evaluate the color of a pixel region?" or "How to assign a single color to a pixel region?". I would try the median of all the pixel in your mask/roi region.

Comment: Perfect..!! If you want, you can answer it with little more detail to get a reputation credits. But your reputation is over 10,000... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Converting hex color to RGB and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-color-to-rgb-and-vice-versa)

If you already have the shirt segmented, you can take the mean/median rgb prior to hex conversion.  If you are using this for recognition, I would also set up the primary axes of your color ellipsoid for specificity.  ie establish range and distribution on each of rgb channels. *you could do center point and sphere (simple color distance) if you are lazy/ it is a simple enough problem*