# How to use hexadecimal values in python instead of RGB value. Python 2.7

Tags: python, pygame

I don't like RGB, I use HEX instead. I'm new to Python and this is how my code is looking like; How do I use HEX. I'm sorry for english I'm not from USA.

```
import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = ("#7ec0ee")

pygame.init()

size = 1024,768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Code for Stack")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

      screen.fill(blue)

      pygame.display.flip()
      clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting hex color to RGB and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-color-to-rgb-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Does `blue = pygame.Color('#7ec0ee')` not do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pygame.Color` supports hex arguments. So you can do this:

```
blue = pygame.Color("#7ec0ee")
screen.fill(blue)
```

This automatically converts your color to RGBA values. So if you went to print the color, you would see:

```
(126, 192, 238, 255)
```

Comment: Also note that pygame comes with a dict of predefined colors, and you can use something like `pygame.Color('white')`, `pygame.Color('lightgrey')` etc etc

Comment: Is the performance impact of using hex arguments any significant?